# Remove review summary from reviews form

Tags: magento2

I want to remove the reviews summary from the reviews form on product pages.

I had some code that works for 2.4.3 but I'm trying to get it to work with 2.4.6

This is where I have got to but I get the error:

"Magento\Framework\Validator\ValidateException: Class "SOMETHING\ReviewDeleteSummary\Rewrite\Magento\Review\Model\NotEmpty" does not exist "

```
namespace SOMETHING\ReviewDeleteSummary\Rewrite\Magento\Review\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Validator\ValidatorChain;

class Review extends \Magento\Review\Model\Review
{
    public function validate()
    {
     
        $errors = [];

    if (!ValidatorChain::is($this->getNickname(), NotEmpty::class)) {
            $errors[] = __('Please enter a nickname.');
        }

    if (!ValidatorChain::is($this->getDetail(), NotEmpty::class)) {
            $errors[] = __('Please enter a review.');
        }

      
    if (empty($errors)) {
            return true;
        }
  
    return $errors;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following `use` instruction :

```php
use Magento\Framework\Validator\NotEmpty;
```

Comment: That now gives me a 302 on /review/product/post/id/222/ but nothing in the exception.log

Comment: This might come from another error somewhere else in the module, but the initial error was because of the missing `use` instruction.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following code :

```
namespace SOMETHING\ReviewDeleteSummary\Rewrite\Magento\Review\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Validator\ValidatorChain;
use Magento\Framework\Validator\NotEmpty as NotEmptyValidator;

class Review extends \Magento\Review\Model\Review
{
   public function validate()
    {
      $errors = [];

      $notEmptyValidator = new NotEmptyValidator();

      if (!$notEmptyValidator->isValid($this->getNickname())) {
         $errors[] = __('Please enter a nickname.');
      }

      if (!$notEmptyValidator->isValid($this->getDetail())) {
        $errors[] = __('Please enter a review.');
      }

      if (empty($errors)) {
         return true;
      }

      return $errors;
    }
 }
```